# Audio playback from assembly language in Unix?

Tags: audio, libraries, x86, interface, assembly

## Looking for a simple audio interface for Unix

For fun, I'm learning x86 assembly language by porting an old game. The trickiest part is finding a way to play simple sounds (square waves, mostly). The game currently expects to be able to write directly to the speaker. How can I most easily play audio in current Unix systems?

### Criteria

To be more precise, this is what I'm looking for (most important criteria first):

1. Can play a waveform. (8-bit, 8000Hz is fine).
2. Simple enough to call from assembly language.
3. Works on a modern Debian GNU/Linux system without needing root for more than simple package installation.
4. Users will not have to install (m)any libraries or other dependencies.
5. Portable across as many UNIX systems as possible. (Particularly {Net,Free,Open}BSD. I expect Solaris, MacOS, and WSL may have their own ways of doing things.)

#### Preferences

The code I'm porting is 32-bit x86 assembly language and I'd rather not convert it to 64-bit at this time. Also, the code does not need to link with libc and it would be nice to keep it that way, if possible.

---

##### Research

Here are some of the avenues I have researched:

- `/dev/audio`

  This is what I had hoped would work: I'd just open [`/dev/audio`](https://man.netbsd.org/audio.4) as a file and write bytes to it. Unfortunately, it appears that the Linux kernel no longer comes with that device by default, so folks would have to install a kernel module (snd-pcm-oss) as root. (Also, although this is a lesser issue, Linux uses the old SunOS semantics and does not allow multiplexing).
- Direct speaker access (`/dev/tty0`, `/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr`)

  This is what the game was original written to use. However, writing directly to a PC's builtin speaker requires root to configure and a kernel module (pcspkr) under Linux. Also, it does not work on laptops and other machines that don't even have a PC speaker attached.
- ALSA

  Linux does come with a sound system that is available without a kernel module called the Advanced Linux Sound Architecture (ALSA). Other Unix systems can [emulate it](https://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/current/pkgsrc/audio/alsa-lib/index.html), although I'm not sure how well. It requires a lot more setup and although it appears it could be controlled directly through ioctl, in general it needs an external library (alsa-lib). The interface is ugly in pure assembly, but can be done in C. On Linux, ALSA is inherently dynamically linked and also uses dlopen to loads up even more libraries (pulse, pipewire) at runtime depending upon the configuration. This is a problem because the assembly code I'm working on is 32-bit, but most 64-bit boxes won't have 32-bit versions of libalsa, pulse, and pipewire installed.
- Pipe to a fork/exec'd program

  A syscall to `pipe(2)` could be used to create file descriptors so the game can just send raw data to a program, such as sox's [play](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/sox/play.1.en.html) command, executed in a fork. While this has the nice property of pushing the problem of portability onto some other program, I'd rather avoid a runtime dependency on an external program.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple enough to call from assembly language.

UNIX systems are all based on the idea that the C calling convention allows you to call into functionality. That is a very fundamental principle! The histories of C and UNIX are interwoven, for a reason.

> Portable across as many UNIX systems as possible. (Particularly {Net,Free,Open}BSD. I expect Solaris, MacOS, and WSL may have their own ways of doing things.)

You can scratch that from your list. If you stay in assembly, you're writing towards a specific ABI. There's nothing you can change about that. Because it's a large endeavour to port assembly to other OSes, C was invented. You're 50 years behind the curve!

> This is a problem because the assembly code I'm working on is 32-bit, but most 64-bit boxes won't have 32-bit versions of libalsa, pulse, and pipewire installed.

Well, luckily, that's not true for the larger desktop distros, which still ship compatibility layers for 32 bit. (so, the 32 bit libraries)

But honestly, that's a hoop you'll have to jump through when you support a platform that's been essentially a legacy mode for 20 years on most machines. You'll need the bare minimum of a 32 bit environment.

> The interface is ugly in pure assembly, but can be done in C.

So, yes, you will have to set up your registers as the x86-Linux ABI C calling convention expects you to, and call into C functionality. (I suspect you'll have to do that for graphics, keyboard IO and other things, as well, anyways.)

Wouldn't recommend directly calling into libalsa, though, even if this adds yet another dependency, but use the slim `portaudio` library that makes reduces the number of complicated function calls you have to do.

So, in all honesty, typically such porting efforts of taking assembly and porting it to modern OSes on modern computers are more or less a rewrite in C or some other language. If you can live with being limited to 32 bit x86, the most probably most sensible way forward is identifyig functional core units in your game, like "this is the main loop", "this is the subroutine called for updating the image in the frame buffer", "this is the subroutine called for getting keyboard state", and converting their outer structure to C, and have *inline assembly* in these C skeletons. Then, you can at the place where your program queries the keyboard controller's memory address just instead call your input library, directly from C. The place you need to shift samples to a sound system you would take the buffer that your assembly filled with samples, and pass the address to the right portaudio function, and so on.

You'll find that learning assembly on a hosted platform takes the shape of filling a programming language with a runtime that is compatible with the paradigms of the platform, and not trying to call the platform from inherently incompatible assembly.